# What if my test cases need data from database, not an empty database?

Tags: python, database, testing, pytest, testcase

I recently started to write test codes and I got curious about setting up database for test.

Let's say that my web server has a feature that calculates all the data from users and verify the output.

In this case, I would need lots of original(remaining) data in my database.

But in another case, I need to check if my web server if it redirects user to the right page according to existence of specific data.

This is my test fixture code and as you can see, in `db.teardown` it drops all data.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def app(request):
    settings_override = {
        'DEBUG': False,
        'TESTING': True,
        'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': f'{DB_CONFIG["VENDOR"]}://{DB_CONFIG["USER_NAME"]}:{DB_CONFIG["PWD"]}@{DB_CONFIG["HOST"]}/{DB_CONFIG["SCHEMA"]}'
    }
    app = _app
    app.config.update(settings_override)
    ctx = app.app_context()
    ctx.push()

    def teardown():
        ctx.pop()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return app


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def db(app, request):
    _db.app = app
    _db.create_all()

    def teardown():
        _db.drop_all()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return _db


@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def client(app):
    _client = app.test_client()

    def get_user_config():
        conf = {
            'user_imin': USER_CONFIG['user_imin'],
            'user_token': encrypt_imin_random(USER_CONFIG['user_imin']),
        }
        return conf

    _client.application.config.update(get_user_config())
    return _client


@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def session(db, request):
    conn = db.engine.connect()
    transaction = conn.begin()
    options = dict(bind=conn, binds={})
    session = db.create_scoped_session(options=options)
    db.session = session

    def teardown():
        transaction.rollback()
        conn.close()
        session.remove()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return session
```

My data will still be there if I comment out the line but then I can't test some cases that needs to be done with empty dataset.

I thought setting up more fixture to start with so that I can

I think it would be great if there is an option for test case to decide whether it does its job as if dataset is empty or not.

If there isn't, what is the best case to set up test suite in my case?

Comment: For those who is also stumbled upon this problem, consider clearing data in a test case, and rollback at teardown phase. I was dropping the whole database at teardown phase, but it seems much more reasonable to drop in the case and rollback at teardown phase.

Answer (score 0):

You can start each test with an empty database. This way your tests are all independent of each other. For the tests which need data, set up the tests by populating the database with data. You probably want to reuse code to do this. You can dump some of the data from a production database to store with your tests to use as a standard test set.

Comment: I think what you said is normally what people do. But I am afraid to do so because some tests need so many data like 200,000 rows and those rows are dependant on other data as well, which means that I have to produce another data on which the other data depend. I think this is the last option that I got. I was looking for more convenient and better way to do it.

Comment: Is there any way to break down the test to require less data? Do you iterate through all 200,000 rows in your test?

Comment: At some of tests, I would. I've decided not to drop database at session level, but clear in test cases that need to be empty.